# How to assign integer to a cell in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to iterate through a dataframe and create a new column with the indice returned by `enumerate()`, but I'm unable to assign the value as integer and I need to convert it later. Is there a solution to do that in one shot ?

As you can see, direct assignment of an integer fails.

```
df.loc[indexes, ('route', 'id')] = int(i)
print(df.loc[indexes, ('route', 'id')].dtypes)  # float64
```

Conversion with a second line of code is necessary:

```
df.loc[indexes, ('route', 'id')] = df.loc[indexes, ('route', 'id')].astype(int)
print(df.loc[indexes, ('route', 'id')].dtypes)  # int64
```

Comment: If you assign an integer to a particular cell, the column that cell is in has NaN everywhere else. Because of that, it can only be represented in float64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28648923/9330208) link shows you how to assing the value of a column to an int type in pandas.
Basically you can do this by using:

1. **to_numeric()** - provides functionality to safely convert non-numeric types (e.g. strings) to a suitable numeric type. (See also to_datetime() and to_timedelta().)
2. **astype()** - convert (almost) any type to (almost) any other type (even if it's not necessarily sensible to do so). Also allows you to convert to categorial types (very useful).
3. **infer_objects()** - a utility method to convert object columns holding Python objects to a pandas type if possible.
4. **convert_dtypes()** - convert DataFrame columns to the "best possible" dtype that supports pd.NA (pandas' object to indicate a missing value).